API Gateway and Lambda: Async call
I have a REST API gateway that receives a POST from a client and pass this POST to a Lambda, adding to be an assync call. However, I want the gateway to return to the client before the lambda processing. Right now I'm getting an error from the Lambda code, so the gateway is waiting for the lambda to finish.
Post from client to gateway:
payload = {
    'token': 'aa',
    'challenge': 'bb',
    'type': 'url_verification'
}

Post from gateway to lambda
{'body': 
    {'token': 'aa', 
    'challenge': 'bb', 
    'type': 'url_verification'}, 
'X-Amz-Invocation-Type': 'Event'}

Return from gateway to client
Status Code: 200
 Response Text: {"errorMessage": "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not     dict", "errorType": "TypeError"... 

Basically this error is from the main.py code in the lambda function. But to the client this does not matter, I only want the client to know that the gateway received the message and called lambda.

Keeping Lambda directly behind API gateway might not be a good option in this scenario. It is preferable to have a SQS between API gateway and Lambda to ensure that the consumers of the API is not getting impacted.

If the messages need to be replayed incase of failures, it can done internally in the system without asking the client to send the message again.

Would the SQS solve the problem of allowing the gateway to return to the client before the lambda processing?

API gateway will return Http 200 after putting message into SQS given that the model validation has passed. It will not wait for the lambda to pickup the message for processing. However SQS has limit on the maximum message size, 256 KB. You may also use S3 instead of SQS if the payload size is more than 256 KB. In that case API gateway will return http 200 after successfully putting the message into S3. You may trigger lambda at the back of S3 event.
